# I am trying to run this code below, which is giving me error

Tags: python, rss

This is part of a code for text summarization using NLTK:

```
import urllib
feed_xml = urllib.urlopen('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml').read()
feed = BeautifulSoup(feed_xml.decode('utf8'))
to_summarize = map(lambda p: p.text, feed.find_all('guid'))
fs = FrequencySummarizer()
for article_url in to_summarize[:5]:
    title, text = get_only_text(article_url)
    print ('----------------------------------')
    print (title)
for s in fs.summarize(text, 2):
    print ('*',s)
```

Here is the error

```
C:\Python34>2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\2.py", line 2, in <module>
feed_xml = urllib.urlopen('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml').read()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Comment: What did you try until now to localize your error ? Show us your efforts.

Comment: In case you are wondering why your question is being downvoted: the most likely reasons are that your title is rather terrible (describe the problem itself, not that you have a problem, *all* questions ask for help), and the error message is trivially googleable, with the answer readily available for you had you searched.

Answer (score 1):

Try `urllib.request.urlopen()` instead of `urllib.urlopen()`

Comment: i tried that .......gives me a new error of "module doesn't have attribute request"

Comment: and have you tried `urllib2.urlopen()` just in case?